# IF, AND, OR function with multi conditions in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

how to combine these 3 formula in one ?

```
=IF(F39<=20000;(F39)*0.1)

=IF(AND(20000<F39;F39<=50000);(F39)*0.15)

=IF(F39>50000;(F39)*0.2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=f39*(0.1+(f39>20000)*0.05+(f39>50000)*0.05)
```